# Regex in Notepad ++ - Remove the line break “\n” after a “$” character in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file containing many instances of block text that are $ separated. After each $ sign, there is a line break. How do I remove this line break after each dollar sign using the Regex search option in Notepad ++?

Update on Bohemians answer:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You should be able to use the extended search/replace instead of the regex search/replace too.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, but it was not working, hence my post to this site.

Comment: Then it would have been good to include that attempt in your question :)

Comment: I guess you are right Jerry. I was just lazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to escape the `$`:

```
Search: \$[\n\r]+
Replace: $
```

Without escaping, `$` means "end of line".

Comment: Hi Bohemian, please update to my answer. I am trying this in Notepad ++ but I get an error as per screenshot

Comment: PlTry that change. I was forgetting about windows new lines

Comment: The search text `\$\R` should also work or `\$\R+` if multiple blank lines before the `$` are to be removed. See `\R` in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html

Answer (score 4):

That's what worked for me.

```
Search: $[\n\r]+
Replace:
```

the Replace is not empty, it's one space stroke `[space]`
[image]

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. They want to remove linebreak after **the character $** (**not** end of line)

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind to match all the newline characters which are next to the `$` symbol. Replacing the matched `\n` characters with empty string will give you the desired result.

```
(?<=\$)\n
```

If you want to remove one or more newline characters present just after to `$` then add a `+` after `\n` in your regex.

```
(?<=\$)\n+
```

Use the below regex if you want to remove one or more new line or carriage return characters.

```
(?<=\$)[\r\n]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wU8uM7/21)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Extended mode`, not `Regular Expresssion` and you can do:

Find what: `$\n`
Replace with: `$`

Comment: Thank you, but it says cannot find "$\n"...In extended mode

Comment: @DextrousDave I believe it will work with `$\r\n` on extended mode. (and you should see `CRLF` when you 'show newlines' on notepad++` to show that there is both `\r` and `\n` in your file.